# Unable to drill through second story subfloor

Tags: drill, joists, subfloor

I have squeaky floors on my second story. I bought one of those repair kits with the tool that helps find the joists through carpet. Wherever I drill, no matter which room or what distance I move along, the bit won't go more than an inch before it stops and seems to hit steel! I've made sure the bit is properly secured repeatedly. I even tried drilling one of the fastening screws just to see what would happen and it's the same. Nothing will break through beyond the plywood. What did they do?!

Comment: Wood joists and a subfloor(plywood) is one type of building a second floor.  Concrete could have been used also.  Without knowing type of house/building we are just guessing.  Either open up the ceiling on first floor or remove a small section second floor, would be nice if you have a closet or hidden space to do this, instead of in the middle.

Comment: Try drilling a few(4 or5) inches away from the joists, if only been drilling on supposed joists.  Might have used steel joists.

Comment: It makes no difference where I drill. I'm trying to find the joists. They actually use steel joists in older construction? This house was built in 1985! It's as if there's a whole layer of steel below the plywood! The squeaks sound like wood on wood.

Comment: It sounds weird to me but.  Unless you have have a look see, not much I can tell.  If using a wood drill bit, change to a metal drill bit and see if that helps, but be careful, small steel plates(2x4 inch) are used to protect electric wires and plumbing, to prevent/tell you it is dangerous to drill there.

Comment: You aren't hitting steel or masonry unless you see particles on the bit when you withdraw it. Are you clearing the bit flutes and continuing? To the inexperienced, a clogged bit can feel like hitting an obstruction. If the bit can't clear wood shavings it can't continue without great force.

Comment: If @isherwood's cleaning doesn't check out, you might be hitting concrete. Using a regular drill and a wood drill bit won't get you anywhere. If you switch to a stone drill, does powdery residue come up? If so, you may need to use a hammer drill and stone drill bit.

Comment: Thanks all...this is carpeted second floor. The exploratory bit provided is designed to go through the carpet without harm. If you aren't on a joist it will drill right through the plywood to air. You can then feel when you get to a wooden joist, back it out, then apply the screws that snap off below the surface. The instructions and videos are clear including the one from This Old House.. I just wondered if there was some type of construction that would cause it to meet such an obstruction. The plywood is easy. Then it just stops and makes a crazy noise against whatever obstructs it.

Comment: Make sure your drill is spinning clockwise before you try anything else.

Comment: Yes. LOL! It's going the right way. It wouldn't drill through the plywood otherwise in any case.

Comment: Well, we are throwing darts in the dark here. None of this really makes any sense. Maybe post some photos as a last resort.

Comment: Isherwood4...i totally agree! Good description. I'm just an old woman who knows nothing about construction. Since it's a carpeted floor, that's all photos would show. I appreciate all the input. I was hoping to find out what construction technique or material might have been used that would prevent drilling through the wood flooring in second story bedrooms. I guess I'll just return this repair kit and continue living with the squeaking. Thanks all!